# Property of Borel measure?

Tags: measure-theory

If $ \mu $ is a finite Borel measure on $R^n $ and if $B_1(x)$ denotes an open ball of radius 1 centered at x, is it true that for compact subset $K$ of $R^n$ there is a point $x_0$ in $K$ such that $\mu(B_1(x_0)) = inf \{ \mu( B_1(x))| x \in K \} $?
what if we replace inf by sup?

Comment: Is $B_1$ an open or a closed ball?

Comment: @NateEldredge open ball.. Sorry for not accurating that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming $\mu$ is a positive measure.  Let $\chi_x$ be the indicator function of $B_1(x)$.  If $x_n \to x$, $\liminf_{n \to \infty} \chi_{x_n}(y) \ge \chi_x(y)$ so by
Fatou's lemma, $\liminf_{n \to \infty} \mu(B_1(x_n)) \ge \int \liminf_{n \to \infty} \chi_{x_n}(y)\ d\mu(y) \ge \mu(B_1(x))$.  Thus $x \to \mu(B_1(x))$ is lower semicontinuous.
A lower semicontinuous function on a compact set attains its minimum.

If you replace inf by sup, consider $n=1$ where $\mu$ is the sum of Lebesgue measure on $[0,2]$ and a unit point mass at $0$.